# Hiding the Master View Controller in a Split View Controller in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a button to the Master View Controller to hide itself. I would like to have another button in a separate view to toggle showing and hiding the Master View Controller. Ive started with the Master Detail template project in Xcode.

I am being told that it is impossible to make these buttons show or hide the Master View Controller in iOS 6 as there is no API for it.

Is this even true? Why would Apple take away this functionality?

If this is true, is there anyway around it? Surely showing and hiding a view in a split controller programmatically should be fairly straight forward?

**EDIT :**

This is not true. The Master View Controller can be hidden from the Detail View Controller using `[self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]`.

Comment: Edit your old question if you want to slightly change it.

Comment: In that question I am asking one question. In this question I am asking several, and making it specifically about iOS6. If what you say is true, and Master View Controllers have a way more limited API in iOS6, then this question is looking for alternate ways to solve the problem. This is why I think it deserves another question rather than a massive edit to my original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the Facebook app for iPad?

Try this library - I've used it many times with great success! 
https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Comment: Possibly more appropriate: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/

Comment: Thanks guys, I will look into these alternate methods.